How to get card details by cardReference Omnipay
How do I get card details later using card reference in unoapp-dev/omnipay-moneris
$card = $this->gateway->createCard(['card' => $card])->send();
$ref = $card->getCardReference();

Something like
$cardDetials = $this->gateway->getCardDetails(['cardReference' => $ref]);

Or
$cardDetials = $this->gateway->fetchProfile(['cardReference' => $ref]);

I tried to get card details after creating card using cardReference, couldn't find any documentations.
expect to get ```expiry_year, expiry_month```


Define what you data you expect "card details" would contain?

First, I use this version in composer.json:
"require": {
    "unoapp-dev/omnipay-moneris": "2.2.0"
}

and I try these codes, and I do not use laravel framework:
<?php
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
use Omnipay\Moneris\Gateway;

try {
    $gateway = new Gateway();
    $response = $gateway->createCard([
        'card' => [
            'email' => 'user@example.com',
            'number' => '7777888899990000',
            'expiryMonth' => '12',
            'expiryYear' => '2038'
        ]
    ])->send();
    if ($response->isSuccessful()) {
        echo "success\n";
    } else {
        echo "fail\n";
    }
    print_r($response->getData());exit;
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo '<pre>';
    echo 'errMsg：'.$e->getMessage().'  line-no：'.$e->getLine().'    trace：'.$e->getTraceAsString();
}

after run, you can use method "$response->isSuccessful()", if true, means success. but in var "$gateway", it does not have method "gateway->getCardDetails" or "gateway->fetchProfile".
if you want to get the reponse detail, can use "$response->getData()".
wish to help u!

I would like to validate cards expiry_month, expiry_year for installments payment to check if there any card that will expire soon. This cron job will run in every month.
so I can send an email with a link to update their card.

I do not find the method that can get the card detail in "unoapp-dev/omnipay-moneris": "2.2.0", but u can try this advise:   (1). use the createCard()->send() method, according to the result, if $response->isSuccessful() return true, use method $response->getData() can get a card detail xml doc, in the xml , it has param expdate like "0222", get it and store it in a database like Mysql.    (2) write cron php code to deal expire date card, qurey from db, if it expires just send email , etc.         wish to help u!    just a  mind.

That is a good Idea. But I have many transaction already happened and didn't saved expiry dates to db. Only I have saved is cardReference

Referred by Moneris developers portal. It has many API.
https://developer.moneris.com/Documentation/NA/E-Commerce%20Solutions/API/Vault?lang=php
The Vault Get Expiring API can get the expired card, u can try.

and the core class MpgClasses can find in github:
https://github.com/Moneris/eCommerce-Unified-API-PHP/blob/master/mpgClasses.php#L1185
To refer the api doc and MpgClasses class, u can write your own many implementations.
